# How do I set up a group mailing list

Tags: civicontribute

I want to send a new event listing to all our members who have ticked a requesting information from us. At the moment when I choose the new mailing list option it's just a blank screen

Comment: Hi Debbie - welcome to the community support area. Folk will do their best to help, but you can help them help you by providing as much info as possible including links (anonymised if necessary ie hide your domain but provide everything after the first /), screenshots, and any error messages that may show

Answer (score 1):

The steps for creating a Mailing List are

- create a Group of contacts (from a Search or other method)
- set that Group to be used as a Mailing List

It is unclear what you mean by 'choose a new mailing list option'. It may help if you add some screenshots after (re)reading https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/#group-settings-and-functionality to ensure we are all on the same page about what you are trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This also sound something is broken in your civicrm installation. What happens when you click on Mailing in the menu? Could you then start a new mailing?

Did you try to clear the civicrm caches? by going to https://your-site.com/civicrm/clearcache?reset=1